# Let X be a discrete random variable taking values in some finite set D.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Let X be a discrete random variable taking values in some finite set D.
1)Write the expression for MGF of X.
2)Differentiate MGF n times and set t=0 to obtain E(X^n)

how can I write the expression for MGF of X if it takes values in a set D?? and what does it mean in second part

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Please read https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation in order to format mathematical expression. Also you can use the list environment to makes your post clearer. Then could you provide with an actual title describing your question.

Comment: Could you explain what you have tried, and where you have failed? What to you know about discrete random variables and/or MGF?

Answer (score 0):

Start with:$$M_X(t)=\mathbb Ee^{tX}=\sum_{x\in D}e^{tx}P(X=x)$$and note that e.g. the first derivative is:$$M_X'(t)=\sum_{x\in D}xe^{tx}P(X=x)$$